# formattable package in Shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, formattable

I discovered recently the formattable package for R and I'm trying to use it on shiny but I didn't succeed. Here is the code I found on github:

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(htmlwidgets)


#This is the part that could be added to formattable to allow shiny integration. Not sure about height 100% but the function wont accept NULL
formattableOutput <- function(outputId, width = "100%", height = "100%") {
  shinyWidgetOutput(outputId, "formattable_widget", width, height, package = "formattable")
}

renderFormattable <- function(expr, env = parent.frame(), quoted = FALSE) {
  if (!quoted) { expr <- substitute(expr) } # force quoted
  shinyRenderWidget(expr, formattableOutput, env, quoted = TRUE)
}

#Define a dataframe (example stolen from formattable readme)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David", "Jenny", 
           "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"), 
  age = c(28, 27, 30, 28, 29, 29, 27, 27, 31, 30),
  grade = c("C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"),
  test1_score = c(8.9, 9.5, 9.6, 8.9, 9.1, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 8.5, 8.6),
  test2_score = c(9.1, 9.1, 9.2, 9.1, 8.9, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.1, 8.8),
  final_score = c(9, 9.3, 9.4, 9, 9, 8.9, 9.25, 9.6, 8.8, 8.7),
  registered = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


##################################
# Shiny server
##################################

server <- function(input, output) {

  #use our new function to create an output called formattableexample. We require an explicit call to the as.htmlwidget function as this does not register as an interactive  environment

  output$formattableexample <- renderFormattable({
    as.htmlwidget(
      formattable(df, list(
        age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
        grade = formatter("span",
                          style = x ~ ifelse(x == "A", style(color = "green", font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
        test1_score = color_bar("pink"),
        test2_score = color_bar("pink"),
        final_score = formatter("span",
                                style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(rank(-x) <= 3, "green", "gray")),
                                x ~ sprintf("%.2f (rank: %02d)", x, rank(-x))),
        registered = formatter("span", 
                               style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x, "green", "red")),
                               x ~ icontext(ifelse(x, "ok", "remove"), ifelse(x, "Yes", "No")))
      ))

    )
  })
}

##################################
# Shiny ui
##################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  #use our new function to show the output we just defined. 

  fluidRow(
     box(
      formattableOutput("formattableexample")
    ),
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When I run the app I get the table but not the shiny template. Could you give any help?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use R package "formattable" in shiny dashboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362635/how-to-use-r-package-formattable-in-shiny-dashboard)

Comment: @Carl not really because I cannot replicate neither examples

Answer (score 2):

I will try to break this down into points.

#### Formattable Shiny Functions

The functions for shiny use are already in `formattable`.  See [lines](https://github.com/renkun-ken/formattable/blob/master/R/render.R#L90-L110).  We can eliminate those lines from your code since they are not necessary.

#### Errors in Example

In your example, what is `box`?  Usually that is used to draw a box around a static plot and will not work with `htmlwidgets`.

```
fluidRow(
   box(
    formattableOutput("formattableexample")
  ),
)
```

Also, there is a stray `,` in the above lines from your example.

#### as.htmlwidget Not Necessary

Explicitly converting the `formattable` with `as.htmlwidget` is no longer necessary, so we can eliminate that.

## Working Code

Correcting the errors and removing the lines as mentioned above gives us the following working code.

```
library(shiny)
library(formattable)
library(htmlwidgets)


#Define a dataframe (example stolen from formattable readme)
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David", "Jenny", 
           "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"), 
  age = c(28, 27, 30, 28, 29, 29, 27, 27, 31, 30),
  grade = c("C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"),
  test1_score = c(8.9, 9.5, 9.6, 8.9, 9.1, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 8.5, 8.6),
  test2_score = c(9.1, 9.1, 9.2, 9.1, 8.9, 8.5, 9.2, 9.3, 9.1, 8.8),
  final_score = c(9, 9.3, 9.4, 9, 9, 8.9, 9.25, 9.6, 8.8, 8.7),
  registered = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


##################################
# Shiny server
##################################

server <- function(input, output) {

  #use our new function to create an output called formattableexample. We require an explicit call to the as.htmlwidget function as this does not register as an interactive  environment

  output$formattableexample <- renderFormattable({
      formattable(df, list(
        age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
        grade = formatter("span",
                          style = x ~ ifelse(x == "A", style(color = "green", font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
        test1_score = color_bar("pink"),
        test2_score = color_bar("pink"),
        final_score = formatter("span",
                                style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(rank(-x) <= 3, "green", "gray")),
                                x ~ sprintf("%.2f (rank: %02d)", x, rank(-x))),
        registered = formatter("span", 
                               style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x, "green", "red")),
                               x ~ icontext(ifelse(x, "ok", "remove"), ifelse(x, "Yes", "No")))
      ))
  })
}

##################################
# Shiny ui
##################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  #use our new function to show the output we just defined. 

  fluidRow(
    formattableOutput("formattableexample")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```