# R Shiny : formattable does not change anything

Tags: r, shiny

I'm writing a Shiny app and I would like to use formattable to color some results under conditions. 
I followed the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362635/how-to-use-r-package-formattable-in-shiny-dashboard)
  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40179835/formattable-package-in-shiny-r)
  but none of these worked. Inexplicably, the example below does not color the results (for me at least), though the table is displayed :

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(formattable)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(box(formattableOutput("dat"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

data <- head(mtcars)

  output$dat <- renderFormattable({
    formattable(data, 
                disp = formatter("span", 
                                 style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 200, "green", "gray")))
    )
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Does somebody have a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is from KoderKow (https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-shiny-formattable-does-not-change-anything/33465) :

The argument after data in formattable() is expecting a list, all we need to do us wrap disp in a list() function. working code below!

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(data.table)
library(formattable)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    tabsetPanel(box(formattableOutput("dat"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  data <- head(mtcars)

  output$dat <- renderFormattable({
    formattable(data, list(
                disp = formatter("span", 
                                 style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x < 200, "green", "gray")))
    ))
  })

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It works now