# Possible to combine DT, formattable and shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, dt, formattable

`Formattable` have some easy options to format table, for example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(formattable)

  df <- formattable(iris, lapply(1:4, function(col){

    area(col = col) ~ color_tile("red", "green")
```

This can later be coverted to a `DT` datatable

```
df <- as.datatable(df)
```

For me it works perfefect to view in the Viewer in RStudion. However, I would like to deploy it as a Shiny app somehow. Complete code:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))


server <- function(input, output){

  df <- formattable(iris, lapply(1:4, function(col){

    area(col = col) ~ color_tile("red", "green")

  }))

  df <- as.datatable(df)

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(df))

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

This does not work, is there any work around? I like the conditional formatting from `formattable`, but would also like to use some options that `DT` offers as  for example filtering, searching, colvis etc.

To just deploy it as a `formattable` there is a thread:

[How to use R package "formattable" in shiny dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33362635/how-to-use-r-package-formattable-in-shiny-dashboard)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it seems to be possible, as also mentioned [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/vignettes/formattable-data-frame.html). Here is some sample code on how to achieve that:

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(formattable)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("input1","Species: ", choices = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table1"))

# make a data.table of the iris dataset. 
df <- iris

server <- function(input, output){

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable( {

    my_df <- df[df$Species==input$input1,]

    return(as.datatable(formattable(my_df, lapply(1:4, function(col){area(col = col) ~ color_tile("red", "green")}))))
  }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Did you manage to run this on your computer? I copy pasted and getting bracket errors, but everything seems ok...

Comment: Sorry, that was sloppy. I made a modification to my code while already copied to Stack Overflow, but I missed a bracket. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: How can I add addtional argument to DT now? For example escape rownames.

Comment: You can pass all arguments in the as.datatable call, the function is described in [the documentation of formattable](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/formattable/formattable.pdf). Hope this helps!